# A computed field in Hasura that returns an array of integer

Tags: postgresql, hasura

### The problem

I am trying to add computed field that returns an array of integer. Hasura currently supports return types of either `SETOF <table-name>` or `BASE` type. I tried returning an `integer[]` but it is failing (it is not a `BASE` type). Is there a work around ?

### Here is What I tried

I have two tables: courses and quizzes, a course have many quizzes, each quiz have an integer field named difficulty.
I want to add a computed field to the courses table that lists the distinct difficulties of the related quizzes.

With SQL we can create an array that produce this list with this query:

```sql
SELECT array(SELECT DISTINCT difficulty FROM quizzes
  WHERE course_id = 1 ORDER BY difficulty ASC);
```

So I create a function that returns the result of this query, and add it as a calculated field on the courses table

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION courses_quiz_difficulties(course_row courses)
RETURNS integer[] AS $$
  SELECT array(SELECT DISTINCT difficulty FROM quizzes
  WHERE course_id = course_row.id ORDER BY difficulty ASC);
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

When I try to add the computed field, I get an error because and array of int is not a BASE type.

> in table "courses": in computed field "quiz_difficulties": the computed field "quiz_difficulties" cannot be added to table "courses" because the function "courses_quiz_difficulties" returning type _int4 is not a BASE type

Is there a work around to make it work with Hasura?

Here is the corresponding documentation:

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/computed-fields.html#supported-sql-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple view gave me the result I wanted:

```sql
CREATE VIEW course_quiz_difficulties AS        
    SELECT 
        course_id, 
        array_agg(DISTINCT difficulty ORDER BY difficulty) as quiz_difficulties
    FROM quizzes GROUP BY course_id
```

After that we can manually add a relationship between courses and the new view:
`courses . id  → course_quiz_difficulties . course_id`

Hasura allows us to query quiz_difficulties from `courses`:

```
query MyCourseQuizDifficulties {
  courses(limit: 1) {
    id
    quiz_difficulties {
      quiz_difficulties
    }
  }
}
```

And we get this result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "courses": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quiz_difficulties": {
          "quiz_difficulties": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```